# How to add uninstall shortcut to Wix bootstrap?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut, bootstrapper, wix3.6

I’m trying to prepare installer with bootstrap. Everything works but I’m failing to add shortcut for uninstalling app. I tried to add uninstall shortcut to main installer but this uninstall only files and leave information in control panel about installed applications. Is there any way to add shortcut to create shortcut to bootstrap uninstaller?

Comment: What do you mean by `mail installer`?

Comment: I misspell it… not mail but main. I know how to do this in normal installer but how to do this in bundle?

Comment: Here are two somewhat helpful links:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-and-uninstall-shortcut-td7587878.html
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/WiX-Bootstrapper-Bundle-creating-uninstall-shortcut-in-program-files-td7580364.html

Answer (score -1):

Add an uninstall shortcut to start menu like this:

```
<Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"             
      Name="Uninstall My Application"
      Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"
      Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"
      Description="Uninstalls My Application" />
```

This sample taken from http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_uninstall_shortcut.html which shows you the complete wix project file.

Comment: I saw this sample but my question is how to add this to bootstrap (bundle.wxs). Above one uninstalls files but leaves bootstrap installer in system.